# Is Morningstar data reliable?

Tags: data, market-data

Wondering if Morningstar financial statement data reliable?

For example it doesn't have [the Balance Sheet statement for BHP](https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xlon/bhp/financials), while Marketwatch [has it](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/bhp/financials/balance-sheet).

Same for [Renault SA](https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xpar/rno/financials) the Balance Sheet is missing.

And for [Novo Nordisk A/S ADR](https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/nvo/financials) financial statements are missing for 2019 year, while they do exist [on Marketwatch](https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/nvo/financials).

Those are really huge companies, how Morningstar could miss financial reports for those?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd look on Morningstar for balance sheet data of publicly traded corporations.

Comment: @DimitriVulis as far as I know Bloomberg and Morningstar are two biggest financial providers. So I supposed they should somehow check and validate the data. But I don't really care about Morningstar, is there a better place to get that information?